# Compare Two separate lists, of the same type, for a specific property and select entries based on the condition

Tags: c#, .net, software-design

Good Day,

I am new to C#. I have three lists(two are mainly important, the third one is for validating). All of them are of the same type. The type is a class that I made, in which I have all my desired variables.

```
public class viewCoordinatesExtended : ViewCoordinates
{
  public int x2 { get; set; }
  public int y2 { get; set; }
  public int height { get; set; }
  public int width { get; set; }
}
List<viewCoordinatesExtended> TSOCoord = new List<viewCoordinatesExtended>();
List<viewCoordinatesExtended> ITEMCoord2 = new List<viewCoordinatesExtended>();
List<viewCoordinatesExtended> CheckCoord = new List<viewCoordinatesExtended>();
```

I populate these lists based on some reading form a PDF files. and they have coordinates of the desired text.

My condition is, that where ever the check list's entry y2 and y2 entries of the other two lists have a difference of less than 10, only those entries should be left in the list, the others should be removed.

The only way I know until now is 3 foreach loops, but it is not an efficient way.

Can someone guide me towards a better way to solve.

I have already removes some entries from the list using where methods.

```
tsoCoords = tsoCoords.Where(x => x.locatedOnPage.Equals(1) && (x.height <= 6)).ToList();
pnCoords = pnCoords.Where(x => x.locatedOnPage.Equals(1) && (x.height <= 6)).ToList();
checkCoords = checkCoords.Where(x => x.locatedOnPage.Equals(1) && (x.height <= 6)).ToList();
```

Still there are a number of entries that need to be removed based on the check list.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to remove any entries where there's a y2 value that doesn't appear in all 3 lists? Is that right? Otherwise it might help if you posted what the triple for each loop would do. Even if it's not efficient it would show us what you're trying to do.

Comment: For a clear understanding of your requirement we either need your original triple-loop code, a worked example with actual input and output data, or you need to rephrase the following key sentence: "My condition is, that where ever the check list, y2 entries of the other two lists, only those entries should be left in the list, the others should be removed."

Comment: My Bad. Actually I want to match y2 of TSO List and PN list against the Check List. Where ever the difference is less than 10, I need to save only those entries

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Edited the post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. 1) I don't understand how this is a "3 list problem". To me it sounds like you want to check _a_ list against `CheckCoord` but need to do this two times. 2) How do you define the `y2` difference if there are multiple reference `y2`s in `CheckCoord`? Are the lists related by index, i.e. `TSOCoord[0].y2` is checked against `CheckCoord[0].y2`, `TSOCoord[1].y2` against `CheckCoord[1].y2` and so on? It would be easiest if you add an example of inputs and expected outputs to your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry same here. If you're saying you know you can do it with 3 nested loops then I suggest you show us that, working the way you want it to, and then we can tell you if it can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment I'm interpreting your question as saying you want to remove all entries in the lists who don't have Y-values that are seen in all three lists. (If I'm off there please clarify but the principle here will be the same).

There are two ways I can think of to do this. One involves `HashSet` and the other involves sorting all three lists and using 3 iterators (but one foreach loop). Both have *roughly* the same efficiency but the hashset method is easier to code and understand so that's what I'll show.

```
    public void CleanupLists()
    {
        // Set1 is biggest
        var set1 = new HashSet<int>(TSOCoord.Select(c => c.y2));

        // Set2 and finalSet will hold ever smaller collections
        var set2 = new HashSet<int>();
        var finalSet = new HashSet<int>();

        // Build set2 based on what's in both TSOCoord and ITEMCoord2
        foreach (var coord in ITEMCoord2)
        {
            if (set1.Contains(coord.y2))
                set2.Add(coord.y2);
        }

        // Build finalSet based on what's in all three
        foreach (var coord in CheckCoord)
        {
            if (set2.Contains(coord.y2))
                finalSet.Add(coord.y2);
        }

        // Filter the original lists based on y2 values
        // shared by all three
        TSOCoord = TSOCoord.Where(c => finalSet.Contains(c.y2)).ToList();
        ITEMCoord2 = ITEMCoord2.Where(c => finalSet.Contains(c.y2)).ToList();
        CheckCoord = CheckCoord.Where(c => finalSet.Contains(c.y2)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: My Bad. Actually I want to match y2 of TSO List and PN list against the Check List. Where ever the difference is less than 10, I need to save only those entries